# How to remove old paint from deck

Tags: paint, deck, stain, paint-removal

I am wits end for trying to get old paint of our deck. Its been starting to chip so we wanted to remove it and stain. So far I have tried the following:

Pressure washer. both electric and gas - doesn't seem to take the paint off and im worried i may damage the wood.
Chemical stripper - again, followed the instructions and only removes a little bit of the paint.
I rented a random orbital sander from Home Depot and used 36grit and then 60grit, this worked a lot better but still has a bout 25% of the paint still on in what I would describe as the 'low' spots of the wood which the larger sander wont reach.
I have a smaller palm sander but my deck is about 250 sq ft so it will take way too long.

Any suggestions?! Thanks

Comment: The old paint was done well.  Removing it takes more work.

Comment: Its a bit hard t make suggestions without photos

Comment: Now that you've removed the bulk of the old paint mechanically you'll probably have a lot more success with the chemical stripper to get the rest off.

Comment: go composite, never paint again.